# functions in forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have been reading the book **JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 7th Edition", in this book is included forEach example that I am not able to get it:

```
let data = [1,2,3,4,5]
data.forEach(function(v, i, a) { a[i] = v + 1; });
console.log(data);  //[2,3,4,5,6]
```

I do not know how the parameters `v, i, a` are getting its value from the data array. If I change the order instead of (v, i ,a), then I get different result. Why it has to be in this order (value, index, array)? I have not been able to find why this strict order.

For example, this other snippet is very straighforward:

```
let sum=0;    
data.forEach((value) => {sum+= value;});
```

each element of data is passed to the body of the arrow function and it is adding the value and storing in sum which adds them up.

Can you please provide insight about the first example?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to your new bestest coding friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - scroll down and you see `forEach(function callbackFn(element, index, array){ ... })` -- https://developer.mozilla.org is amazing and I go there often

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the forEach method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. It will pass you those arguments in those order. The **names of the variables are not important** but the order is because that's how functions work. You can do `data.forEach(x, index, theData) => ...`

Comment: These are positional parameters. As the name suggests, the _position_ matters.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the syntx of the `Array.prototype.forEach()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

There is not much to say about the order, it's just the intended way of using the interface. You could use red, green and yellow for all intends and purposes, but the order would stay the same.

First param will be the element value, second one the index and third the array itself.

```js
let data = [1,2,3,4,5]
data.forEach(function(red, green, yellow) { yellow[green] = red + 1; });
console.log(data);  //[2,3,4,5,6]

data.forEach(function(value, index, array) { array[index] = value + 1; });
console.log(data);  //[3,4,5,6,7]
```

In newer versions of JS you could do something like

```
const array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]

for (const number of array) {
  console.log(number)
}


for (const [number, index] of array.entries()) {
  console.log(`${number} has ${index}`)
}
```

And since the naming of the objects do only matter inside the `forEach()` scope, you could simply set them to something that makes sense in the context you are in, so your iteration gets easier to read and understand. E.g.: `for (const car of cars) {//car go honk}`

See for `.entries()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries

Answer (score 0):

data.forEach funciton need a function as a parameter.
and that function defined as function(value,index,array).you can pass a function with less parameters Eg:function(value),function(value,index).but you can't pass wrong order.
becuase inside the forEach() function.you can image it did like this

```js
//Just for Example.real code not like this
Array.forEach = function(callback){
    for(var i in this){
        callback(this[i],i,this);
    }    
}
```

Comment: this, although technically correct, just seems to make it less clear (to me). It's probably good just to get OP used to reading documentation and https://developer.mozilla.org couldn't be more clear

Comment: Change it to `for..of` and it would be more correct. Older versions of js would iterate through all the indexes in the array then also pass `length`, `map`, `forEach` etc into the value of `i`. Newer versions fixed this but does not help when someone extends Array prototype or add a custom property to the array.

Comment: @Kinglish your are right.here I just want give a short brief.I should give the mozillia link here.that's more clear

Comment: @nay - you were spot on (still have to change it to a `for...of` tho) and your example showed how to abstract the callback out to another function. All good, but I like to encourage people to find the basic answers at the source (teaching them how to fish).

Comment: I have a question about`for of` that it only get value not get the index.where I can get index and pass to to `callback(value,index.array)`

Comment: I have that example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68042729/16174836